# AngularJS infinite digest loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm passing an object to an AngularJS directive like so:

```
<context-selector
            is-buy="true"
            num-to-select="0"
            init-object="{ads: rule.ads_list, adContainer: rule.container_ad_id, campaign: rule.campaign_id}">
        </context-selector>
```

and it causes Angular infinite digest loop because of the init-object.
I guess that's because Angular compares the object by reference.
The directive definition is:

```
directive('contextSelector', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                vertical: "@",
                levelsDepth: "@",
                isBuy: "@",
                shellsLeft: "=",
                numToSelect: "@",
                initObject: "=" // {ads: [1,2], adContainer: 4, campaign: 6}
            },
```

Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I did some more searching on google, I came up with this post:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4054

Apparently it's a known issue and was fixed in Angular >= 1.2.5

Comment: Yes. I was able to reproduce with this basic example http://plnkr.co/edit/3wKmWz?p=preview